# res.json(item) responds with [object Object]?

Tags: json, node.js, angularjs, express, mongoose

I have a MEAN stack, where I loop over the items in the db with ng-repeat, and {{ items.value }} populates text on some divs. The divs each have `ng-click="getItem(item._id)"` to trigger an angular page redirect to

```
// dynamic pages for each ITEM, on ng-click
// from $routeParams.itemID in Ctrl
.when('/:itemID', {
    templateUrl: 'views/item.html',
    controller: 'ItemElementsController'
})
```

Creating, Retreiving All, and Deleting works great.. Retreiving One is responding with [object Object] though, so localhost:8080/undefined and the angular bindings {{ items.value }} are not populated

```
app.get('/api/items/:item_id', function(req, res) {

    // use mongoose to get the one emotion from the database
    Item.findById({
        _id : req.params.item_id
    },

    function(err, item) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err) {
          res.json({ error: err }); 
        } else {
            res.json(item); // return the item in JSON format
        }
    });
});
```

In the ItemElementsController:

```
angular.module('ItemElementsCtrl', [])

// inject the Item service.factory into our controller
.controller('ItemElementsController', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, $http, ItemElements, isEmptyObjectFilter) {

        // GET by ID ==================================================================
        // get an Item after clicking it
        $scope.getItem = function(id) {
                ItemElements.getOne(id)
                        // if successful getByID, call our function to get the Item data
                        .success(function(data) {
                                // assign our Item
                                $scope.item = data;
                                // for use with a parameter in appRoutes.js using itemID as the variable
                                $scope.itemID = $routeParams.itemID;
                                // redirect
                                $location.path('/' + $routeParams.itemID);
                        })
                        .error(function(data) {
                                console.log('Error: ' + data);
                        });
        };
});
```

And the ItemElementsService:

```
angular.module('ItemElementsService', [])

    // super simple service
    // each function returns a promise object 
    .factory('ItemElements', function($http) {
        return {
            getOne : function(id) {
                return $http.get('/api/items/' + id);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

$routeParams.itemID doesn't have itemID parameter at this moment. It will be filled with data when your route will be '/:itemId' but now you are on '/list' or something like this (I dont see all your routes).

```
.controller('ItemElementsController', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, $http, ItemElements, isEmptyObjectFilter) {
    if ($routeParams.itemID !== undefinned){
             ItemElements.getOne($routeParams.itemID)
                    // if successful getByID, call our function to get the Item data
                    .success(function(data) {
                            // assign our Item
                            $scope.item = data;
                            // for use with a parameter in appRoutes.js using itemID as the variable
                            $scope.itemID = $routeParams.itemID;
                    })
                    .error(function(data) {
                            console.log('Error: ' + data);
                    });
    }
    // GET by ID ==================================================================
    // get an Item after clicking it
    $scope.getItem = function(id) {
            $location.path('/' + id);
    };
```

Comment: thanks for the better practice.. am still getting the data back as undefined, where even the url reads http://localhost:1122/undefined ... any suggestions?

Comment: could you add console log after $scope.getItem = function(id) {console.log(id); ...} and show the result. It look like you have problem with id parameter.

Comment: it's logging the id now! thanks for that.. and localhost:1122/5343a882f35199e102000001, but the angular binding {{ item.value }} in the item.html file that we redirect to are not populated, and node's console.log(emotion) is still undefined

Comment: It is ok, because you use $location.path(...), and this function refresh you current $scope.

Comment: how can we get at the item data that should be in $scope.emotion = data ?

Comment: I updated 'ItemElementsController' please see, this fix problem with binding {{item.value}}. Don't forget clean browser cache.

Comment: thanks for that, but it's still not working.. `data is not defined` when I console.log